# For Each com Where e Break By

Tags: progress-4gl

Não consegui encontrar um título adequado para a minha dúvida, mas vamos lá...
Considerando o trecho de código abaixo como exemplo:

```
def temp-table tt-test
    field id       as int
    field customer as int
    field added    as char.

create tt-test.
assign tt-test.id       = 1
       tt-test.customer = 100
       tt-test.added    = "".
create tt-test.
assign tt-test.id       = 2
       tt-test.customer = 100
       tt-test.added    = "".
create tt-test.
assign tt-test.id       = 3
       tt-test.customer = 100
       tt-test.added    = "".
create tt-test.
assign tt-test.id       = 4
       tt-test.customer = 100
       tt-test.added    = "".

def buffer b-tt-test for tt-test.

for each tt-test
   where tt-test.added <> "S"
   break by tt-test.customer:

    if tt-test.id = 2 then
        for first b-tt-test
            where b-tt-test.id = 4:
            assign b-tt-test.added = "S".
        end.

    disp tt-test.id
         tt-test.added
         last-of(tt-test.customer).
end.
```

**Qual problema estou enfrentando:** o `for each` continua trazendo o registro de `id = 4` sendo que esse registro teve o campo `added` setado para "S", e no `where` do `for each` existe uma condição `tt-test.added <> "S"`, ou seja, pela lógica ele não deveria aparecer.

**O que eu preciso:** no caso do código acima, preciso que o `last-of(tt-test.customer)` seja o registro de `id = 3`, visto que o registro de `id = 4` não deveria mais ser lido pelo `for each`.

**A título de curiosidade:** se retirar a cláusula `break by` do `for each`, então o registro de `id = 4` não é lido, mas em contrapartida sem o `break by` não posso usar o `last-of`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que vc precisa saber é que seria impossível ter um LAST-OF ou FIRST-OF sem uma pré-seleção dos registros. Por isso o registro 4 aparece com o break by, porque ele foi pré-selecionado antes mesmo da primeira iteração do laço ocorrer.
O ideal seria vc alterar os registros que podem estar à frente em um laço e fazer um for each sem restrições a seguir, tendo então dois laços, ou, se esse processo tiver que ser feito simultaneamente ao display, adicione um if antes do display.

Se você só queria uma resposta, pode parar de ler. Como um conselho, lembre-se que o display (a menos que isso seja um relatório com saída que não seja o terminal) pode levar tempo pra ser visualizado pelo usuário, e como vc está alterando o registro, o Progress automaticamente faz upgrade do bloco para uma transação, pra poder acomodar o seu assign. Você não explicitou um lock, então o Progress assume SHARE-LOCK. Se isso fosse uma tabela física, o Progress seguraria o lock enquanto o usuário está olhando os registros. Isso aumenta a chance de um dead lock.

Muito embora vc esteja trabalhando com temp-tables, eu evitaria essas construções pra não acontecer de mais tarde você acabar fazendo o mesmo com tabelas físicas. Acostume-se a escrever blocos com lock explícito (NO-LOCK ou EXCLUSIVE-LOCK, sempre), e defina as transações em blocos específicos. Tente ao máximo fazer iterações de leitura serem seu próprio bloco com no-lock, e seus updates dentro de blocos com exclusive-lock, e com transações explicitadas (de novo, pra temp-table em geral não precisa), essas boas práticas vão te poupar bastante dor de cabeça no futuro.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Acabei descobrindo que para solucionar minha situação basta adicionar um índice na temp-table com o campo added ou customer, assim o registro de número 4 desaparece e o last-of passa a ser o registro de id = 3.